# Jquery window.location.replace, redirects to only base URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, .htaccess, seo, base-url

I'm using .htaccess (mod rewrite) to have pretty looking SEO friendly URLs. I have a form where user could change his / her account's password. I provide information with Jquery to the user that his / her password has changed and in 3 seconds page will be redirected to login page.

```
setTimeout(function() {window.location.replace("http://localhost/projects/v4/login/#login");} , 3000);
```

For some reason this code redirects to `http://localhost/projects/v4/#login` instead of `http://localhost/projects/v4/login/#login`. I mentioned about SEO friendly URLs in the begining of my question. I started to think this problem occurs because I am using base URL between `<head></head>` element.

```
<base href="http://localhost/projects/v4/" />
```

Is there any solution for this problem or am I mistaken and this problem occurs because of some totally different problem?

**.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /projects/v4/

RewriteRule ^index/ index.php [L]

# MEMBERS
ReWriteRule ^login/(.*) ?module=login&a=$1 [L]

# MODULES
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)$ ?module=$1 [L]

# LAST ONES
#RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?(ref=.*)?\ HTTP [NC]
#RewriteRule .? http://localhost/projects/v4%{REQUEST_URI}? [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
```

Thank you for your time and concern.

Comment: Why your `BASE` path differs from page URL's path? I mean shouldn't they both be equal `http://localhost/projects/v4/login/` when you are at the Login page?

Comment: Do I have to change base URL in each page in my html because I'am using mod rewrite? This doesn't sound useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You issue is not caused by JavaScript, but by your `.htaccess` file. Make sure that your rules are correct, and not conflicting.

The `[R=301,L]` rule should be last, because it matches every URL at `v4`, including login. Also, swap `MODULES` and `MEMBERS`, because the module rule also matches the member rule.

```
# MEMBERS
ReWriteRule ^login/(.*)/ ?module=login&a=$1 [L]

# MODULER
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ ?module=$1 [L]
RewriteRule .? http://localhost/projects/v4%{REQUEST_URI}? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. I made the changes. Swapped MODULES and MEMBERS and took `RewriteRule .? http://localhost/projects/v4%{REQUEST_URI}? [R=301,L]` rule to the bottom. This time I get **The page isn't redirecting properly** when I try to visit any page :(

Comment: You also have to move `RewriteCond` with the last rule (I forgot to copy it in my answer).

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't help. It still goes back to base URL / `RewriteBase` in **.htaccess** file for some reason. PHP can redirect correctly but Javascript can't.

Comment: Thanks Rob. I made the changes but still I'm being redirected to base url :( I have it in v4/ folder. Some folders also has .htaccess file. Except the main one, rest of it is just protecting files and / or turning off mod rewrite.

Comment: Removing `RewriteBase` rule didn't help. I'm using **XAMPP**. My project is under `htdocs/projects/v4/`.  I am not sure how moving .htaccess file to one folder up will solve this problem. Thank you very much for your help and time.

Comment: Have a look at http://pastebin.com/b195inXw Are the rewrites behaving as expected?

Comment: Yes they are. Sorry for the delay. Just javascript redirect is not behaving as expected.

Comment: @Pixeler So, in a browser, the redirects are working as intended, while the redirect is broken in your script? That sounds unlikely. Can you mention which redirects are (not) working? **PS.** Remove some comments which are not important, to clean up.

Comment: Hello Rob. All redirect rules **in .htaccess file** are working without any problem thanks to you. Just `window.location.replace("http://localhost/projects/v4/login/#login");` or `window.location.href = "http://localhost/projects/v4/login/#login";` redirects to `http://localhost/projects/v4/` instead of where it should redirect.

Comment: Can you add a `RewriteLog` rule (see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog), and check the logs? If you manually enter `http://localhost/projects/v4/login/#` in the browser, where do you get?

Comment: I got internal server error. I am reading about RewriteLog. When I manually visit that URL, I am seeing log in page as I am supposed to.

Comment: Thank you Rob W. You helped me a lot. Problem was with .htaccess indeed.